# QML и javascript

Tags: javascript, qt5, qml

Добрый день. Создаю программу для работы с картами. Функционал довольно таки не простой и разрабатывается на Qt C++. Для первого показа приложения использую QQuickWidget, чтобы отображать карту. Очень понравился QML, но я до сих пор вожусь с тем, что не понимаю до конца как устроено взаимодействие с js, а точнее работа с qml типами.

Предлагаю посмотреть на примере. Стоит задача нанести несколько gps треков на карту. Треки представлены в GPX формате (это обыкновенный xml. [Пример](http://pastebin.com/5FixAPpH)). Ради эксперимента я их отображаю в ListView

```
Rectangle {
    id: rectmp
    width: 300
    height: 300

    XmlListModel {
        id: xmlModel
        source: "qrc:/gpx.gpx"
        query: "/gpx/trk/trkseg/trkpt"

        XmlRole { name: "lat"; query: "@lat/string()"}
        XmlRole { name: "lon"; query: "@lon/string()"}
    }

    ListView {
        width: 200; height: 300
        model: xmlModel
        delegate: Text { text: "lat:" + lat + " lon:" + lon}
    }
}
```

На выходе получаю список координат. Это конечно хорошо, но я не могу сообразить как элегантно передать эти данные в, например MapPolyLine?

С сырыми данными в документации это выглядит так:

```
MapPolyline {
        id: track1
        line.width: 3
        line.color: 'green'
        path: [
            { latitude: -27, longitude: 153.0 },
            { latitude: -27, longitude: 154.1 },
            { latitude: -28, longitude: 153.5 },
            { latitude: -29, longitude: 153.5 }
        ]
    }
```

, где { latitude: -27, longitude: 153.0 } - это тип coordinate. А как внести значения lat и lon из xml не могу сообразить.

При всем при этом в моем случае кол-во треков различно. Как красиво сделать несколько PolyLine'ов и иметь возможность в дальнейшем работать с каждым из них? Опять же, каждый трек подразумевает под собой работу с мышью и т.д. Отсюда еще вопрос: как аналогично C и JS сделать несколько объектов одного класса в QML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Слишком много вопросов в одном, не нужно так делать. Для получения пути для полилинии из XML модели, Вы можете воспользоваться примерно таким кодом:

```
XmlListModel {
    id: xmlModel
    source: "qrc:/gpx.gpx"
    query: "/gpx/trk/trkseg/trkpt"

    XmlRole { name: "lat"; query: "@lat/string()"}
    XmlRole { name: "lon"; query: "@lon/string()"}
    onStatusChanged: {
        if (status == XmlListModel.Ready) {
            var points = [];
            for(var i=0; i < count; i++) {
                var item = get(i);
                points.push({latitude: item.lat, longitude: item.lon});
            }
            track1.path = points;
        }
    }
}
```

Я его не проверял, но должен работать.
Чтобы работать с мышкой в QML есть [`MouseArea`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-mousearea.html). Создание компонентов описано в [Dynamic QML Object Creation from JavaScript](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-javascript-dynamicobjectcreation.html), обычные JS классы можно создавать через `new`, но Вам вряд ли это понадобится.

Comment: вас понял. Спасибо за разъяснения. Ваш код работает! Только было неочевидно, что так можно. Видать, дело опыта.

Comment: По поводу того, что создание компонентов не пригодится. Тогда как,  например, отобразить несколько треков красивым кодом? Может 2, а может 10. Не прописывать же XmlListModel для каждого.
Есть идея, создать ListView с путями, а потом делегировать отображение XmlListModel

Comment: @VladislavBuzdin, я говорил про JS классы, компоненты иногда приходится создавать. Что касается того, как правильно делать: всё приходит с опытом. Изучайте примеры, смотрите, что да как — изучайте документацию. Лично я предпочитаю всю модель собирать в C++, а в QML заниматься исключительно отображением модели. И, кстати, если мой ответ Вам помог — отметьте его галкой(рядом с ответом), это примет его как ответ на вопрос.